# why ubuntu try to connect Amazon server as root when starting?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

After starting the ubuntu, I open nethogs immediately and I notice one connection try to connect  Amazon CloudFront

```
user   program                                       dev
root    192.168.1.XXX:...52.84.31.219:443.....       wlan0
```

After a while, the connection disappear.

I check the ip 52.84.31.219

```
Details for 52.84.31.219
IP: 52.84.31.219
Decimal:    877928411
Hostname:   server-52-84-31-219.ewr50.r.cloudfront.net
ASN:    16509
ISP:    Amazon CloudFront
Organization:   Amazon CloudFront
Services:   None detected
Type:   Corporate
Assignment: Static IP
Blacklist:  ￼Click to Check Blacklist Status
Continent:  North America
Country:    United States ￼
State/Region:   Washington
City:   Seattle
```